# How to check whether the WIFI the user is using is password protected

Tags: ios, passwords, wiki, ssid, bssid

How to check whether the WIFI (SSID, BSSID) the user is using is password protected from iOS API?

Answer (score 0):

There are no public APIs in the iOS SDK for determining if the access point you're currently connected to is password protected.